# Cannot change PPT title font with officer

Tags: r, fonts, title, officer

Title font not changing in Powerpoints created with officer.

I have tried adding fp_text into ph_with, and while it runs nothing it produced from it.

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

title.font <- fp_text(font.size = 28)    

example_pp <- read_pptx() %>% 
  # LMS slide ----  
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  ph_with(paste("Title font test"),
          location = ph_location_type(type = "title"), 
          fp_text(font.size = 28))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no argument for `fp_text` in `ph_with`.

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

example_pp <- read_pptx() %>% 
  # LMS slide ----  
add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  ph_with(block_list(fpar(ftext("Title font test", prop = fp_text(font.size = 28, color = "red")))),
          location = ph_location_type(type = "title") )
```

See `?block_list`

Comment: Thank you David! Always nice to see a package author be involved in helping users.

Comment: Along these same lines, how would we then center the title? Am I correct in thinking that would be with `fp_par(text.align = "center"`? Everywhere I've tried to place that has either not worked, or printed the word "center".

Comment: You can have a look at the documentation of fpar, there is an illustration for your need: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/fpar.html#examples